# How to return 0 instead of NULL in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm having some trouble joining the contents of two tables. I want 0 instead of NULL in the result. 
Here's the current situation:

table1

```
Name    v1       v2
A       1         2
B       5         3
C       8         4
```

table2

```
Name    v3       v4    Id
B       8        12    1
B       7        22    3
C       6         4    2
```

Result

```
Name    v3       v4 
A       NULL     NULL
B       8        12
C       NULL     NULL
```

Expected Result

```
Name    v3       v4 
A        0        0
B        8       12
C        0        0
```

I've tried the following to achieve the result:

```
select t1.Name,
    (select coalesce(v3,0) from table2 where Name = t1.Name and id =1),    
    (select coalesce(v4,0) from table2 where Name= t1.Name and id =1)
from table1 t1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `coalesce` outside subquery

```
select t1.Name,
       coalesce((select v3 from table2 where Name= t1.Name and id = 1), 0),
       coalesce((select v4 from table2 where Name= t1.Name and id = 1), 0)
  from table1 t1
```

or better, use left join instead correlated subqueries (correlated subqueries in value list should be terrible slow on larger than small tables).

```
select t1.name, coalesce(t2.v3, 0), coalesce(t2.v4, 0)
  from table1 t1 
       left join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t2.id = 1;
```

Comment: To explain why, the subqueries run on each row of `table1` and use the returned row to fill in the value. `select ... from table2 where Name = t1.Name and id =1` returns no rows when `t1.name` is `A` or `C`, so the `coalesce` doesn't even get a chance to run.